# .Net endpoint not found - memory full

Tags: c#, .net

There are around 100 PC's in my network. Each PC has a script that is run on 'Task Scheduler' at a certain time. The purpose of the script is to move .csv files to a server as a backup.
I'm trying to make a better solution, and include the solution in .Net application(MVC) that I'm working on right now. The solution is working smoothly. I test 3 PC's and moved the files to the server, there were around 200 files(5GB). However, when I run the application again, I was not able to open the endpoint anymore. I was assuming that the cache memory is full, when I clear all history and clear that cache memory the endpoint is ok.
Below is the function where the magic happens(there is another for loop for allAhrons - allPcs).

How can I solved the problem? Any possible solution is much appreciated!

```
var numberOfTotalFiles = 0;
foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(allAhorns[i].Sourcepath.Trim()).GetFiles())
{
  NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, pwd);
  CredentialCache theNetCache = new CredentialCache(); 
  theNetCache.Add(new Uri(@"\\" + allAhorns[i].Sourcepath), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
    
  file.MoveTo($@"{fullDestinationPath}\{file.Name}");
    
  numberOfTotalFiles++;
}
```

Comment: First thing I see is that you are creating the credential cache inside the loop.  It would make more sense to do that outside the loop so you don't create a new cache on the root directory for every file in it.

Comment: I will try to remove CredentialCache since I believe this line doesn't do anything. NetworkCredentials and CredentialCache I found them on doc.Microsoft, without those two I had an error: Access Denied.  I might be wrong, but I will test it again without CredentialCache.

Comment: If you need it, just move it outside the loop.  You are setting it at the root directory.  The way it is now, if there are 5000 files, you create a new cache and add the root URI 5000 times.